# Regex that allows all international characters but no symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I already wrote the following Regex that allows all international characters (Latin, Asian, ...)

```
 'Düsseldorf, Köln, Москва, 北京市, إسرائيل !@#$'.match(/[\p{L}-]+/ug)
```

But I would like to make it **not** allowing all special characters like `!?})%....`

Comment: Do you mean you only allow letters and hyphens in the string? `/^[\p{L}-]+$/u`?

Comment: I would suggest that you use character ranges (ex [a-z][A-Z][...])

Comment: the other thing you could do is make a negative pattern just with the characters you don't want and negate that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Yes the regex also allows hyphens `-`

Comment: Does `/^[\p{L}-]+$/u` answer the question?

Comment: @ControlAltDel how would the negate Regex look like ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, that does not resolve my problem.

Comment: Ok, so it is not clear. You have `Düsseldorf, Köln, Москва, 北京市, إسرائيل !@#$`. What do you need to get in the end?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like that the following string for example not matches: `'北京市?!'.match(/^[\p{L}-]+$/u)`

Comment: It does not match. What do you want to achieve? Please help us help you.

Comment: negative regex: /[^!\?})...]/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matching string containing only letters, numbers, dashes, dots, commas and whitespace:

```js
console.log(
  /^[\p{L},.0-9\s-]+$/u.test('Düsseldorf, Köln, Москва, 北京市, إسرائيل !@#$')
)
console.log(
  /^[\p{L},.0-9\s-]+$/u.test('Düsseldorf, Köln, Москва, 北京市, إسرائيل')
)
```

**Results**: `false` and `true`.

**EXPLANATION**

```js
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\p{L},.0-9\s-]+         any character of: letter, ',', '.',
                           '0' to '9', whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " "), '-' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Yes.. this is the other option.. but make sure to exclude e.g. arabic numbers and all other UTF-16 non letter characters as well

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, javascript regular expressions (compared to other programming languages) still have a poor support for UTF-8/UTF-16 characters, even if it is a planned feature.

Currently, there is no other option (I know) than to add ranges, which should look like:

```
new RegExp(/^[ \-.a-zšđčćžÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$/i).test('St. Petersburg')
```

From your examples, it looks like you are looking for full UTF-16 support, so you will have to add some ranges yourself.
You can use https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm as a reference. It includes a description to identify which chars are letters and which not.

Answer (score 1):

There's a book called "Javascript, The Good Parts" that provides some good examples on this, in short you can do something like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \u00C0-\u1FFF\u2800-\uFFFD]+$/
```